# PHP page going blank after sometime of time out

Tags: php, mysql, html

I have set my PHP page to refresh and get values from the database , the problem is that it goes blank after sometimes. The refreshing part and everything works fine. Only thing is that the page goes blank

Code i used for refreshing the page is:

```
$url=$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
header("Refresh: 1; URL=$url")
```

Comment: May want to look into AJAX requests instead of relying on refreshing.

Comment: Or use an iframe which is refreshed from outside...

Comment: Try to add some cache control to avoid caching by the browser.

Comment: how? to use cache control

Answer (score 0):

Place an iframe which calls your page to refresh inside a static page. Then refresh this iframe every second. Using this pattern it breaks not the functionality when the dynamic page returns blank once.

**Simple Example**

```
<html>

<script>
    setInterval("reload()", 2000);

    function reload(){
         document.getElementById('refresh').src = "./page_to_refresh.php";
    }
</script>

<iframe id="refresh" src="./page_to_refresh.php">
</html>
```

Comment: cant i use something related to html only? i want to refresh the tables and its contents

Comment: You can, but if your page breaks once it will never recover again without user interaction!